# How do I remove part of a filename using listIndexOf()?

Tags: java

I have these files :

```
 Hingga Akhir Nanti - Allycats_part001
, Hingga Akhir Nanti - Allycats_part002
, Hingga Akhir Nanti - Allycats_part003
```

I would like to remove the `"_part001"` onwards and replace it with extension `.mp3` for all files in the folder ..

Any ideas on how to do that in Java?

Answer (score 3):

I hope this snippet should help you.

```
/**
 * Pass your file names here as a comma separated values
 * @param strs
 * @return nothing
 */
 public static void convertToMp3Extenesion(String... strs) {
  for (String string : strs) {
    File file  = new File(string);
    if (!file.exists()){
    continue;
    }
    String replacedFileName = string.replaceAll("_part\\d+", ".mp3");

    file.renameTo(new File(replacedFileName));
  }
```

In order to take all the files from one directory , you can enhance the above snippet as,

```
/**
 * pass your directory containg your files
 * @param directory name
 * @return nothing
 */
 public static void convertToMp3Extenesion(String dir) {

 File fileDir = new File(dir);
 if (!fileDir.isDirectory()) {
 System.err.println(dir +" is not a valid directory ");
 return;
 }

 String[] strs = fileDir.list();
  //use if for debug. not so good, if files are too many
 //System.out.println("All Files "+Arrays.toString(strs));
 for (String string : strs) {

   File file  = new File(dir+ File.separator+ string);
   if (!file.exists()) {
      continue;
   }
   String replacedFileName = string.replaceAll("_part\\d+", ".mp3");

   file.renameTo(new File(dir+ File.separator+ replacedFileName));
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! It's working fine. But I was wondering if it's possible to automate a code to read the filenames instead of hard coding it?

Comment: I keep getting error when I pass the dir 'File dir = new File("D:\\Music\\Assembled\\");'

Comment: Hi thanks again for helping! It works even though it only changes one of the files to .mp3

Comment: what is the actual name of that file ?

Comment: Actual name: Hingga Akhir Nanti - Allycats.mp3  

Right now I have the files that has been split into:  
 
Hingga Akhir Nanti - Allycats_part001  
Hingga Akhir Nanti - Allycats_part002  
Hingga Akhir Nanti - Allycats_part003
  

And I need to change it to Hingga Akhir Nanti - Allycats.mp3
to assemble it back to original file

Answer (score 2):

you can use a regex `myFileName.replaceAll("_part\\d+", ".mp3")`  and then use the file's renameTo() method to apply the new name.

I believe the string it takes is the full path to the file, so be careful to include that (if I'm correct on that front).